# Type 'number' is not assignable to type '[string | number, string]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got this error, when i try to format the currency value.

```
type CurrencyState = {
    ...,
    initialValue: [number | string, string];
}

let formatedValue = this.state.initialValue;

        if (typeof formatedValue === 'string'){
            formatedValue = parseInt(formatedValue)
        }
        formatedValue = Intl.NumberFormat("en", { style: "decimal", minimumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(formatedValue );
```

Comment: I guess the type should just be `number | string`, not `[number | string, string]`.

Comment: `initialValue` is array but you try to set `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined `initialValue`'s type means that it has to be an array, where its first value is either a number or a string, and its second value is a string.

In your code you check if `initialValue` is a string, which it can never be.

So either remove the brackets from the type, to make it `number | string`, or treat `initialValue` as an array of 2 values like so:
`typeof formatedValue[0] === 'string'`